# OAuth2.0 support for IMAP - GMAIL API for Email Aliases

Tags: gmail-api

We are in the process of moving to GMAIL API's for OAuth2.0. I have a use case where I have 15 email aliases on a mailbox. During the app authentication can I give access to only two email aliases. Will I be able to get a different access token only for those two email aliases?. Or the access and refresh token is generated per mailbox.

Answer (score 2):

OAuth grants and the resultant tokens are scoped to Google users and their services. There's no way to limit which aliases / sendAs addresses of the user the grant can utilize.